# $f(x+1)=f(x)+1 \Rightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}x=1 ?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, solution-verification

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continous function such that $f(x+1)=f(x)+1 $   for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ . Then which of the following statements is necessarily false ?.

$(1)\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)} {x^{1+\epsilon}}=0$ for all $\epsilon \gt 0$

$(2)\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)} {x}$ does not exist .

$(3)
\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)} {x}=1$

$(4)\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)} {x^{1-\epsilon}}=+\infty$ for all $\epsilon \gt 0$

My attempt:

$f(x)=x$ satisfies the hypothesis and makes the result   in $(1), (3) $ and $(4)$ true and so they are **not** necessarily false .

I need to prove $(2)$ is necessarily false i.e the limit **does** exist.

It can be easily proved by induction

$f(x+n)=f(x)+n$ for all $ n\in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Let $x\gt 1$ be any real number.Then

$x=\lfloor x\rfloor +\overline{ x } \quad(*)$

where the first part is greatest integer and the second is fractional part and is less than $1$ .

Then  $f(x)=f(\overline {x})+ \lfloor x \rfloor $

Now $f$ being continous on $[0,1]$ is bounded above by some $M$ on $[0,1]$ .

Hence , we have $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {f(\overline{ x })}x=0$

Thus $ \displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {f(x)}x= \displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {\lfloor x \rfloor }x$

Now again using $(*)$ , we have

$1=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {\overline{x}}x+\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {\lfloor x \rfloor }x $

$\Rightarrow  
   \displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {\lfloor x \rfloor }x=1$ since $0\le \overline {x}\lt 1$

Thus the limit exist and is equal to $1$.

Is everything okay ? Any alternative ideas/solution will be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is fine and I don't think there is a better proof.

Comment: Side note: A more common notation for the fractional part of a real number is with curly braces: $\{ x \}$.

Comment: @Martin R Personally I think Wolfram's notation $\operatorname{frac}(x)$ is the most clear.

Comment: @K.defaoite: Agreed. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) calls it $\operatorname{frac}(x)$ but also mentions $\{ x \}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is fine. Using the perhaps more common notation $\{ x \}$ for the fractional part of $x$, you showed that
$$
\frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{f(\{ x \})}{x} + \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x}
$$
where the first fraction converges to zero (because the numerator is bounded) and the second fraction converges to one (because $x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$).

Instead of  fiddling with the integer and fractional parts of $x$ one can also argue as follows: $g(x) = f(x) - x$ is continuous and $1$-periodic, and therefore bounded. It follows that
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{g(x)}x=0 \implies 
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}x=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{g(x)+x}x=1 \, .
$$

Comment: Wow !! Smart trick :)  Thanks .